# How to add uitabbarcontroller as a subview in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to iPhone development... Now I am trying to build an application in which the user is first shown a login screen. In this view there is no navigation control .

Once the user logged in, i want to show a new view, which has tabbar control. Based on the tab item selected in the tabbar ... the view being show could have just a table view or table view + navigationbar control.

Any help on this could be done ?

I am able build a small application to login screen and validate user credentials .. 
Also a different application where i build a tabbarviewcontroller and show associate various views to the each of the tabbar item.

But not sure to combine the both.So the problem is that i don’t know how to add the UITabbarController as a second view

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this. remove the login view from main window and tabbarcontroller's view to the main window. You just need to implement some methods in application delegate class.

Comment: Sorry i cant get it clearly... Can you please explain with code snippet??

Answer (score 0):

add tabbatcontroller to ur mainwindow class. whenever you need tabar in app. just remove UINavigationController and add UITabBarController.

or add add tabbatcontroller to ur mainwindow class and just present tababrcontroller from current viewcontroller.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.tCtr.selectedIndex = index;
delegate.tCtr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:delegate.tCtr animated:YES];
```

Comment: Its showing error in console.. Actually i did as you said but in console it shows "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication tabBarController]: unrecognized selector sent"..Do you have any Idea?? My Code is : testTabAppDelegate *del = (testTabAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
 del.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
 del.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [self presentModalViewController:del.tabBarController animated:YES];

Comment: have you given connection del to tababr?

Comment: Still error. I did the following
1. Created view based application
2. Added UITabbarController in appDelegate.h
3. Added Tabbarcontroller using IB to view controller
4. Called Method in view controller with following code:

testTabAppDelegate *del = (testTabAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
del.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
del.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:del.tabBarController animated:YES];

I dint do any connections in IB. Are these steps right?? Am i missing something or lot of things??

Comment: added tababrcontroller in to mainwindow. and connect in to UITabbarController.